# How to create a Text cutout in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to create a Text Box where text colour should be transparent and if I change the colour of the background containter..the text colour should change too. For example, consider this image

[image]

Here, I have a stack with first element a container with `colour= black` because of which I want *MY TEXT* to be black too.
I don't want to manually set the font-colour of the text every time I change the colour of the 1st container.. as I may plan to fill the container with an animation later and I want the same animation to run on the text also.

I tried setting the text **foreground** colour to transparent and background colour to **orange** but that did not help, the text also became orange and hence invisiable.

Comment: Why would you not want to just make the color of the text dependent on the same thing as the background? If you are changing one programmatically I don't understand how changing both is any more complicated.

Comment: like I said in the question, I would later want to change the colour of the background with animation, I want the same animation to be visible in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking out for more options, I found this really simple method to achieve what I wanted.

```
ShaderMask(
          blendMode: BlendMode.srcOut,
          child: Text(
              text,
            ),
          shaderCallback: (bounds) =>
              LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.black], stops: [0.0])
                  .createShader(bounds),
        )
```

Comment: How can I set the size of this? If I wrap the `Text` in a Padding or similar, the black box is still only around the text.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use a `CustomPainter` with a `TextPainter` and a blending mode for that.

[image: example]

In your widget tree:

```
return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      height: 40.0,
      child: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: MyTextPainter(text: 'Hello'),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Your custom text painter:

```
class MyTextPainter extends CustomPainter {
  MyTextPainter({this.text});

  final String text;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        ),
      ),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );
    textPainter.layout();

    // Draw text
    final textOffset = size.center(Offset.zero) - textPainter.size.center(Offset.zero);
    final textRect = textOffset & textPainter.size;

    // Your text box (orange in your example)
    final boxRect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(textRect.inflate(5.0));
    final boxPaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.orange
      ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcOut;

    canvas.saveLayer(boxRect.outerRect, Paint());
    textPainter.paint(canvas, textOffset);
    canvas.drawRRect(boxRect, boxPaint);
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyTextPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good answer, but will it be possible to fill the color with an animation? I want the same animation to be visiable in the text.

Comment: This should work out of the box. Just change the Container's color and text should match automatically, since `shouldRepaint` is always returning `true`, regardless of the `Text` being the same.